# Unresolved overloaded function type when using QtConcurrent for QImage::fill

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to call [QImage::fill()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#fill) asynchronously using the [QtConcurrent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html) module. The [invert pixels example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html#using-member-functions) works fine but a similar syntax for the fill method does not:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QImage>
#include <QFuture>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrentRun>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QImage image(1920, 1080, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
  QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(&image, &QImage::fill, Qt::transparent); // ko
  //QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(&image, &QImage::invertPixels, QImage::InvertRgba); // ok
  future.waitForFinished();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Compilation fails with the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘run(QImage*, <unresolved overloaded function type>, Qt::GlobalColor)’
   10 |   QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(&img, &QImage::fill, Qt::transparent); // ko
      |                                                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtConcurrent/QtConcurrentRun:1,
                 from /home/romain/code/qt/main.cc:4:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentrun.h:72:12: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> QFuture<T> QtConcurrent::run(T (*)())’
   72 | QFuture<T> run(T (*functionPointer)())
      |            ^~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentrun.h:72:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/romain/code/qt/main.cc:10:80: note:   mismatched types ‘T()’ and ‘QImage’
   10 |   QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(&img, &QImage::fill, Qt::transparent); // ko
      |                                                                                ^
```

Is it possible to help the compiler by marking some template types explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `QImage::fill` has multiple overloads.  You need to disambiguate using either `static_cast`...

```
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(&image, static_cast<void(QImage::*)(Qt::GlobalColor)>(&QImage::fill), Qt::transparent);
```

or (since this is `Qt`) [`QOverload`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload)...

```
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(&image, qOverload<Qt::GlobalColor>(&QImage::fill), Qt::transparent);
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you. Note that qOverload() requires C++14 enabled.